# SharePoint View Formatting - IF Null AND

Tags: json, sharepoint, formatting, sharepoint-online

I have an SP list, and have formatted the view with some JSON but on the 'Open' I want to also included IF open AND "people picker field null" Basically I'm want to hightlight something that is open an unassigned to someone

> {
>     "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
>     "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status] == 'Open', 'ms-bgColor-green ms-fontColor-black', if([$Status] == 'Closed', 'ms-bgColor-magentaLight ms-fontColor-black', if([$Status] == 'On Hold - 3rd Party', 'ms-bgColor-magentaLight ms-fontColor-black', if([$Status] == 'On Hold - 3rd Party', 'ms-bgColor-neutralLighterAlt ms-fontColor-black', if([$Status] == 'On Hold - User information', 'ms-bgColor-purpleLight ms-fontColor-black', if([$Status] == 'Closed', 'ms-bgColor-magentaLight ms-fontColor-black',if([$Status] == 'Request Completed Fulfilled','ms-bgColor-teal ms-fontColor-black' ,if([$Status] == 'Cancelled','ms-bgColor-yellow ms-fontColor-black', if([$Status] == 'Rejected Atlas','ms-bgColor-orangeLight ms-fontColor-black' if([$Status] == 'Rejected iHub','ms-bgColor-neutralSecondary ms-fontColor-black', ''))"
>   }

Any help would be cool

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(@currentField <= @now && [$RAG] != 'Live', '#bc1010', '')"
```

&& is used as the and operator. In the example above, i'm looking to see if the time is now, and if the RAG column does not equal Live.